# Are there toxins that cause heart attack and/or stroke in multiple individuals in short time frames?

Tags: cardiology, neurology

Are there any known environmental factors that would cause more than one person to have a heart attack or stroke within a short period of time (e.g. 2-3 months) of one another? I'm particularly looking for causes that are likely to be found around the home (e.g., chronic low-dose CO poisoning), as opposed to industrial sites.

Comment: Could you give us some more details or narrow down your question? I'm afraid right now it reads to me like a request for an entire section of a toxicology text. Many, many substances could lead to a heart attack or stroke. It sounds like you have something specific in mind. What's the context here?

Comment: Candidly, I'm not certain how to be more clear, but maybe that's because I lack expertise in this area. I'm looking for a toxic substance that could reasonably be expected to be found in a house, and that could make the house's occupants likely to have a heart attack or stroke over the course of several weeks or months of exposure. I'd be inclined to exclude things like smoking, as the exposure needed in that case is on the order of years or decades. Does that help?